# Why does this GPS approach say "RADAR REQUIRED"?

Tags: avionics, instrument-procedures

As I was looking at [the approach charts for KCXY](https://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KCXY/ALL/all/pdf) while answering [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23867/why-is-radar-required-on-some-faa-instrument-approaches/24294#24294), I realized that the GPS "overlay-style" approach to RW8 also requires RADAR.

Since the HAR VOR isn't even shown on this Approach, and it has an IF, why should RADAR be required?

Note that the RNAV (GPS) RWY 26 approach to this airport does not require radar.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is radar required on some FAA instrument approaches?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23867/why-is-radar-required-on-some-faa-instrument-approaches)

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that it has to do with the close proximity of Harrisburg MDT. In a non-radar environment, an aircraft flying this approach would surely limit traffic being allowed to approach or depart MDT. Perhaps the RADAR requirement is to limit this approach to use when it would have a minimal impact on MDT traffic.

Comment: @abelenky its not a duplicate of that answer, and in fact, I reference that answer.

Comment: @JonathanWalters by that logic, every approach inside busy airspace would say "RADAR REQUIRED", which we know is not true.

Comment: No, that logic leads to exactly the sort of answer you give for your CAT II / III requirements below. Close proximity creating an impact on traffic for some reason.

Comment: your logic "in heavy traffic areas, RADAR is required to maintain separation" is falsifiable. Mine is not (yet).

Comment: here's an example of an approach under the SFO main approach path that doesn't require radar http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/SQL/IAP/RNAV+(GPS)+Y+RWY+30/pdf

Comment: Not heavy traffic, but close proximity, especially the intersecting approach departure areas. I don't think heavy traffic has anything to do with it. I don't know where you found your quote about heavy traffic.

Comment: i retract the word 'heavy'. the comment stands. nevertheless, you haven't provided any evidence, say AIM or TERPS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34248/discussion-between-jonathan-walters-and-rbp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The immediate reason seems to be that for RNAV approaches that start at an IF (*Intermediate Fix*) - not an IAF (*Initial Approach Fix*) - radar is required per the [ATC orders](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf) (4-8-1h):

> issue approach clearance [...] only after the aircraft is:
>
> 2. Established on a heading or course direct to the IF at an angle not greater than 90 degrees, provided the following conditions are met:
>
> [...]
>
> (b) Radar monitoring is provided to the IF.
>   (c) The SIAP must identify the intermediate fix with the letters “IF.”

The [RNAV 26 approach](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1601/00187R26.PDF) that you mentioned does have an IAF, so according to the same rules radar isn't always required for it.

You might now ask, why is radar required for RNAV approaches that start at an IF? Because, it doesn't have an IAF.

The next question is why doesn't it have an IAF? Probably because of higher terrain north of the approach corridor? Or maybe (as per @Jonathan Walter's answer) there is sufficient Radar coverage to vector to the IF, so it doesn't need an IAF.

Comment: yes, thanks, you found it. There's no way to begin the approach without radar if there's no IAF, as per http://blog.aopa.org/opinionleaders/tag/intermediate-fix/